# How to stop my array from returning multiple arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift, casting, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get info from the Youtube API and having trouble casting items out into my array. Here's what I got.

I'm establishing my public array like this...

```
var videoId = [String]()
```

Here is what the code looks like casting down from jsonresponse of Dictionary...

```
for var i=0; i<items.count; ++i
{
    if let idDict = items[i]["id"] as? NSDictionary
    {
        let id = idDict["videoId"] as! String
        //self.videoId = [id]                    
        self.videoId.append(id)
        print(self.videoId)
```

And here's my response.......

```
["Z32Y5MkdICQ"]
["Z32Y5MkdICQ", "UrNb397wS-A"]
["Z32Y5MkdICQ", "UrNb397wS-A", "vzwoJ10UyO0"]
["Z32Y5MkdICQ", "UrNb397wS-A", "vzwoJ10UyO0", "jBmkCoiHC2c"]
["Z32Y5MkdICQ", "UrNb397wS-A", "vzwoJ10UyO0", "jBmkCoiHC2c", "PzpLkcfBe-A"]
["Z32Y5MkdICQ", "UrNb397wS-A", "vzwoJ10UyO0", "jBmkCoiHC2c", "PzpLkcfBe-A", "DmOvILJAYK8"]
["Z32Y5MkdICQ", "UrNb397wS-A", "vzwoJ10UyO0", "jBmkCoiHC2c", "PzpLkcfBe-A", "DmOvILJAYK8", "E5svXAZ9-Qk"]
["Z32Y5MkdICQ", "UrNb397wS-A", "vzwoJ10UyO0", "jBmkCoiHC2c", "PzpLkcfBe-A", "DmOvILJAYK8", "E5svXAZ9-Qk", "vYH6Sw3A-BA"]
["Z32Y5MkdICQ", "UrNb397wS-A", "vzwoJ10UyO0", "jBmkCoiHC2c", "PzpLkcfBe-A", "DmOvILJAYK8", "E5svXAZ9-Qk", "vYH6Sw3A-BA", "mgZz4L1UmxE"]
["Z32Y5MkdICQ", "UrNb397wS-A", "vzwoJ10UyO0", "jBmkCoiHC2c", "PzpLkcfBe-A", "DmOvILJAYK8", "E5svXAZ9-Qk", "vYH6Sw3A-BA", "mgZz4L1UmxE", "Gh4fgkiUi18"]
```

Of course all I want is the last one which is an array of 10 `videoId`'s.  How can I get this? Also, if you know..can you give me the correct casting process within `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: it is not clear what problem you want to solve, and where in your code, there is a set of arrays, it's just the same array that append single element every cicle iteration

Comment: What happens if you put the call to print outside the for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your print out of the loop! You aren't getting a bunch of different arrays, you are just printing the same array every time you go through the loop and append a new item.

```
for var i=0; i<items.count; ++i
{
    if let idDict = items[i]["id"] as? NSDictionary
    {
        let id = idDict["videoId"] as! String
        //self.videoId = [id]                    
        self.videoId.append(id)
    }
}

print(self.videoId)
```